# Wordpress post content displays without calling/echoing it

Tags: php, wordpress

In my code I didn't echo the_content() or get_the_content()
[My post query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kxEG.png)

But it still outputs all the contents outside my query
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of8hk.png)

When I try to output the content, it works just fine. I just want to remove the extra content at the bottom. this also happens in other post types as well.[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFi7e.png)

Comment: as I see this is section-blog.php file. Are you sure this is not a template part file ? I mean is it possible its called inside a template file where the content of the page is rendered?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors, put them as text in the question. Images are hard to read, links can break, and people cannot copy & paste the code to give it a try. See also [ask].

Comment: the images are noted. Thanks it's fixed now, all it needed was the function wp_reset_query();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

After `endwhile` loop.

After looping through a separate query, `wp_reset_postdata()` restores the $post global to the current post in the main query.

Differences between the main query loop and secondary query loops are:

- the main query loop is based on the URL request and is initialised before theme templates are processed
- secondary query loops are queries (using new WP_Query) in theme template or plugin files

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again :)